# save and load function in java tic tac toe game

Tags: java

I have created a tic tac toe game in java for an assignment for university and it all works ok, and it is already submitted but my question is if I wanted to add extra functionality to the game such as save and load game method, how would I approach this as I have performed basic file reading and writing functions before but this seems more advanced

Any help or even pointers in the right direction would be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This is a very open question. There are primarily to things you need to do. Figure out what kind of data you want to save, and where/how you want to save it. There are a lot of ways to do this. You could use object serialization to get a state of an object (game board??) in a saveable format. Or you could optimize, and extract only the relevant information (name the tiles 1-9, and only save an array of simple integers like this [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0] where 0 represents empty, 1 = X and 2 = O). You can save to a database, or a file or whatever you like. What do you want to learn?

Comment: Share how you maintain the state of game during runtime; may be its an array of integer. And Serialization may be an option to save and load the game state.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't publish any code, I can see two options for you problem.

First one and more complex, you can use the java serializer to serialize the object of your game and save it on a file.

Second one an more simple, you can save in a file an array with 9 positions with 0, 1 and 2. And then load it to your game.

```
public enum PlaceStatus{
    EMPTY(0),
    X(1),
    O(2);

    int value;
    PlaceStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Example of file: `01200100` That means (e represents empty):

```
e | X | O
e | e | X
e | e | e
```

Comment: @jason This solution pretty much answers your question. You may want to accept the solution if your problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, Have you ever worked with databases ? To save the game state, you will need to save the instant state which you would wanna load at latter state.